# Autocomplete without using a callback

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, autocomplete

I want to use autocomplete-fields that link to an external source for their autocomplete-data. Drupal seems to refuse all autocomplete_paths that are not reachable within Drupal. Any ideas how to circumvent that problem? The form field looks like that:

```
$form['business_city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#title' => t('city'),
    '#autocomplete_path' => '_/city?=',
    '#default_value' => $userProfile->field_address_business_city[0]['value'],
);
```

_/city is not reachable within Drupal for performance reasons. The script bootstraps Drupal up to session-level to check for a valid login.

**UPDATE:**

If I create an autcomplete-field by attaching the needed markup manually to the field it works but it is awkward to maintain:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => 'form-autocomplete'),
'#suffix' => '<input type="hidden" disabled="disabled" value="/_/city?n=" id="edit-private-city-autocomplete" class="autocomplete">',
```

Comment: Usually, it's not a good idea, to build a form field without using the form API.

Comment: I decorate the form-field with a hidden field only (by using the forms api). If you have a better idea I'm all ears. The forms api won't allow me to user a non-drupal path for the autocomplete-feature. The only thing I could to is apply a custom theme-function for the textfield which even more code and imho an even greater hacker.

Comment: Outputting `<input>` tags should be done just from the form API. The answers given by @Berdir suggests to override a theme function, which also avoids to output a form field outside a theme function, or the form API.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I got to consider that. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 6 validates in [theme_textfield()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7) if the autocomplete path is a valid (internal) path.

So, you can't work around this unless you override that theme function.

Comment: Ah yeah could have searched for that myself :) Thank you. Got to stick with the hack then.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hacking, you could make sure that the path you are querying "/_/city?n=" is a valid menu_hook item. That way it will validate against the drupal_valid_path() inside theme_textfield(). From within the menu hook function callback you could then forward the request to your external data source.

Comment: Yes and no :) Rerouting the request thru a real menu-hook would jeopardize my performance-efforts which were the initial reason to use an external script. I tried to create a similar named menu-hook to allow drupal to validate the url. The RewriteRule in .htaccess prevents accessing Drupal-urls if a similar file does exist in the file-system so it would have validated against the drupal callback and would have used the external script. The problem was the special url which contains ?n=. I was not able to create a matching callback.